# UISearchBar + array of objects + NSpredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Would you please tell me why my SearchBar doesn´t work in my UITableViewController?

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{    
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                          predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.TitleInside contains[c] %@",
                          searchText];
filteredArray = [HelpList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Why

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";
TableViewCell_Rts *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell){
    cell = [[TableViewCell_Rts alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
CellObject *NewIndex = nil;

if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    NewIndex = [HelpList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
    cell.TitleLabel2.text = NewIndex.TitleInside;
    cell.DescriptionLabel2.text = NewIndex.DescriptionInside;

} else {
    NewIndex= [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.TitleLabel2.text = NewIndex.TitleInside;
    cell.DescriptionLabel2.text = NewIndex.DescriptionInside;   
}
```

CellObject is a NSObject:

```
@interface CellObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ImageInside;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *TitleInside;
@end
```

When i run the application, my tableview looks populated. Then, when i write inside the search bar, the table doesn´t show the results of the search.

Thanks ¡

Comment: Are you in IOS8 ? Have you set the delegate of the searchBar and searchController to your class? Add some NSLog() to see where something is missing.

Comment: Thanks for answering Paul. I´m using XCode 6.1.1. IOS8, I´ve already set the delegate and searchController :(, what else could be?

Comment: I don't know, try to compare your code with this example : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html you have the version in swift and objective-c.

Comment: First, name your iVar starting with a lowerCase (`newIndex`, `imageInside`, etc.). What returns `filteredArray`? What does return the `numberOfRowInSection:` when you perform the search?

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.tableView){
        return [restaurantsList count];
    }else{    
        return [filteredArray count];
    }
} I´m using a break point at "return [filteredArray count];" and the debugger says "filteredArray=(NSArray *) nil "

Comment: filteredArray returns the search results. Thanks @Larme for your recommendation about lowerCases, i´ve already changed my code, but still doesn´t work.

Comment: Do you reload the tableView once your filtered?

Comment: How can i do that? Pdt. there´s a mistake above: restaurantsList = HelpList